# How to define a function that would check if a string have whitespaces after the sentence is finished?

Tags: python

Here's what I've tried so far

```
def whitespace(string):
    for s in string:
        if s[-1] :
        return ("'%s' ended with whitespace." % s)
    else:
       return ("'%s' was whitespace-free." % s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
def whitespace(string):

    if string[-1] == " ":
        return True

    return False
```

You don't need to loop over the string, just access the last element.

This method returns a `boolean`, modify it whatever you want.

Comment: Wuah.. Thank you :) btw if we do not know how many spaces at the end of the sentence. Will the code change too?

Comment: No, this code checks if the last character of the given string is a whitespace. If there are more than one, no problem, the last one will always be a whitespace. If you need to strip them out, check out [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) for the `strip` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions(regex) for this situation:

```
def whitespace(string):
    import re
    if re.searh("\s+$",string)
        return ("'%s' ended with whitespace." % s)
    else:
       return ("'%s' was whitespace-free." % s)
```

- "\s" means find one space
- "\s+" means find one or more spaces
- "\s+$" means find one or more spaces before JUST before the end of the string

Those strings are called regex (regular expression). Python, like many other languages, use those to find strings inside strings. The kind of regex that python uses comes from Perl.

- [Python 3.4 Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)
- [A Perl regex guide](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html)